# Is it possible to pass a Sass variable to Laravel/Blade/JS?

Tags: javascript, laravel, variables, sass, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get a variable I use in Sass over to Laravel/Blade/JS so that I can use one variable defined in one place to maintain something across the various languages used to maintain the site.

Is it possible to pass a Sass variable to Laravel/Blade/JS so I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-to-js

Comment: That works. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome i'll put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library to pass Sass variables to JS.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-to-js

here's an example,

**SASS:**

```
$colorMap: (
  colorHexShort: #f00,
  colorHex: #ff0000,
  colorRgba: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5),
  blackGradations: ('#000', '#111', '#222') 
);
.colors-data{
  &:before{
    content: sassToJs($colorMap);
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**JS:**

```
var colorsDataEl = $('.colors-data');
var colorsData = colorsDataEl.sassToJs({pseudoEl:":before", cssProperty: "content"});
colorsDataEl.html(JSON.stringify(colorsData));
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Webpack, you can do this easily with `:export` without the need for additional dependencies.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [{
        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
      }, {
        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
      }, {
        loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
      }]
    }]
  }
};
```

**variables.scss**

```
$white-color: #fcf5ed;
$dark-color: #402f2b;
$light-color: #e6d5c3;
$medium-color: #977978;
$alert-color: #cb492a;
$light-black-color: #706e72;
$black-color: #414042;

// the :export directive is the magic sauce for webpack
:export {
  whitecolor: $white-color;
  darkcolor: $dark-color;
  lightcolor: $light-color;
  mediumcolor: $medium-color;
  alertcolor: $alert-color;
  lightblackcolor: $light-black-color;
  blackcolor: $black-color;
}
```

**file.js**

```
import variables from 'variables.scss';

const CSS = {
  backgroundColor: variables.blackcolor
}

export default ({}) => {
  return <div style={CSS}>Content</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a kind of custom solution to export your **Sass** variables to a **Js** file.

First my **Sass** variables :

```
$bifurcation                : violet;
$simple                     : green;
$multiple                   : orange;
$crossing                   : yellow;
$common                     : brown;
```

I put them into an unknown **css** property :

```
variable_to_export {
    start_export: unset;
    bifurcation: $bifurcation;
    simple: $simple;
    multiple: $multiple;
    crossing: $crossing;
    common: $common;
    end_export: unset;
}
```

On my **js** file, i'm going to read the compiled **scss** file containing my '*variable_to_export*'. This block of code is in a function that I can export to all my files that need it :

```
export function variables() {
    var variables = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: "/css/global.css",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(css) {
            var position = css.indexOf('start_export');
            var position_end = css.indexOf('end_export');
            var clean = css.slice(position, position_end).replace(/ /g, '').replaceAll(';', '');
            var array_variables = clean.split(/\r?\n/);
       

            array_variables.forEach(function(element) {
                var split = element.split(':');
                if (split[0] != 'start_export' && split[0] != '') {
                    variables[split[0]] = split[1];
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return variables;
}
```

At this stage we have an array containing the name of the **css** property as index, and the value of the **Sass** variable in my desired js files.

[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X6B1.png)

I think there are surely things to improve, the solution is a bit rooty but it works.